# Setting attributes for Python module instead of file name

Tags: python, package

I'm new to packaging up Python so not sure what search term to use.

Inside my package, there is a `_checksum.py`

```
# _checksum.py

class Add():
     def __init__(self, x, y):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y
    
     def answer(self):
           return self.x + self.y
```

So to use them, I'd have to import the file name

```
import MYPACKAGE
import MYPACKAGE._checksum as checksum

test = checksum.Add(3, 4)
test.answer()    #7
```

So my question is is there a way to set alias to `MYPACKAGE._checksum`, maybe something like `from MYPACKAGE import checksum`?

Comment: You're mandatory to use the filename somewhere

Comment: Yeah my question is if there's a way to set attributes in some setup file so the import command wouldn't reveal the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python relies on filename a lot for module importing, just to make it more intuitive. However, if it's for the package users, you can probably do

```
# MYPACKAGE/__init__.py
import ._checksum as checksum
```

So when your users using your package, they can do

```
# Application code
from MYPACKAGE import checksum
```

Comment: Thanks that's really simple.